# @ExceptionHandler not getting called once exception is thrown from REST layer

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I'm developing a REST service using Spring MVC. I'm trying to implement exception handling using @ExceptionHandler . When exception is thrown from REST layer, it's not been intercepted by @ExceptionHandler. Am i missing anything ?

```
@Service
@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerResource extends BaseResource{

@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

 ........

@GET
@Path("/customer/{accountNumber}")
public Response findCustomerByAccountNumber(String accountNumber) throw Exception{
   Customer customer=null;
   customer=customerDao.find(....);
   if(customer==null)
      throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
   else
    ..........

  }
}
```

Base class which has Exception handler method

```
public abstract class BaseResource {

.......

@ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotFoundException.class })    
public Response handleException(Exception ex) {
    ErrorResource errResource = new ErrorResource();
    .....   
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(errResource).build();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing ResourceNotFound but have specified ResourceNotFoundException in the exception handler - these seem to be different exceptions. Either throw ResourceNotFoundException instead of ResourceNotFound or add ResourceNotFound to the exception handler.

**EDIT:**
Don't know how I missed it at first: just noticed you don't actually use Spring MVC controller. Spring MVC exception handlers only work for requests handled by Spring MVC controllers. They handle exceptions that happen in the body of controller handler methods. You seem to use something else to handle REST requests.

Comment: Probably Jersey with Jersey-Spring integration. As the updated answer says - Spring's exception handling is for Spring MVC, not for JAX-RS. OP will need to implement `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` for custom exception handling.